# converting a DateTime column to string in ADF

Tags: sql, azure-data-factory, delta-lake

I am trying to build a fully parametrised pipeline template in ADF. With the work I have done so far, I can do a full load without any issues but when it comes to delta load, it seems like my queries are not working. I believe the reason for this is that my "where" statement looks somewhat like this:

```
SELECT @{item().source_columns} FROM @{item().source_schema}.@{item().source_table} 
WHERE @{item().source_watermarkcolumn} > @{item().max_watermarkcolumn_loaded} AND @{item().source_watermarkcolumn} <= @{activity('Watermarkvalue').output.firstRow.max_watermarkcolumn_loaded}
```

where the 'max_watermarkcolumn_loaded' is a datetime format and the 'activity' output is obviously a string format.

Please correct me if my assumption is wrong and let me know what I can do to fix.

EDIT:
screenshot of the error
[image]

ADF is picking a date from SQL column 'max_watermarkcolumn_loaded' in this format '"2021-09-29T06:11:16.333Z"' and I think thats where the problem is.

Comment: Do you get any error? if yes, share the error message.

Comment: @Aswin i Have edited my post for clarification. Thanks

Comment: Wrap these parameters within single quotes `'@{item().max_watermarkcolumn_loaded}'` and `'@{activity('Watermarkvalue').output.firstRow.max_watermarkcolumn_loaded}'`

Comment: `SELECT @{item().source_columns} FROM @{item().source_schema}.@{item().source_table} 
WHERE @{item().source_watermarkcolumn} > '@{item().max_watermarkcolumn_loaded}' AND @{item().source_watermarkcolumn} <= '@{activity('Watermarkvalue').output.firstRow.max_watermarkcolumn_loaded}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to repro this error. I gave the parameter without single quotes to a sample Query.
[image]

Wrap the date parameters with single quotes.

**Corrected Query**

```sql
SELECT @{item().source_columns} FROM 
@{item().source_schema}.@{item().source_table} 
WHERE @{item().source_watermarkcolumn} > 
'@{item().max_watermarkcolumn_loaded}' AND 
@{item().source_watermarkcolumn} <= 
'@{activity('Watermarkvalue').output.firstRow.max_watermarkcolumn_loaded}'
```

With this query, pipeline is run successfully.
[image]

Comment: thank you! it worked. Could you please explain the significance of the single quotes around parameters?

Comment: WIthout giving single quotes your query will be `SELECT col1 FROM dbo.tab1 WHERE watermarkcolumn>2010-10-10 `. Thats the reason it is necessary to wrap them in single quotes